# Magento 1.7 custom options not updating price

Tags: magento-1.7, javascript, jquery

On a Magento 1.7 website the product option price is not longer updating the main price. I updated the prototype.js file which I though was causing the issue but still no luck. When I inspect the code with Firefox I can see 3 "unreachable code after return statement" on 3 files: calendar.js, product.js, configurable.js

[An example](https://www.marsden-weighing.co.uk/index.php/industrial-scales/platforms-beams-and-pallet-truck-scales/standard-mild-steel-platform-scales/marsden-p-na-i-400-platform-scale.html)

This happened all of a sudden, no code or configuration changes have been made. Any pointers much appreciated.

Comment: What error you getting on console ?

Comment: On firefox console I get this: "unreachable code after return statement" on 3 files: calendar.js, product.js, configurable.js

Comment: That's the error, fix those errors and your problem is solved

Comment: In the end the problem was caused by Feefo widget. Feefo support said that this is causing lots of issues on other Magento websites.

Comment: Great, so finally you debugged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the problem was caused by Feefo widget. Feefo support said that this is causing lots of issues on other Magento websites.